# Issue with Release-Please Workflow for Generating Git Tags and Release Notes

Tags: github-actions, hotfix, github-release

I am currently utilizing the Release-Please GitHub Action workflow for creating SemVer Git Tags, GitHub Releases, and changelog files. In my GitHub repository, I have separate branches for development, staging, and production. The workflow is functioning well for generating Docker image names based on the Git Tags. However, I have encountered a requirement to create a tag every time a feature branch is merged. This need can still be met by the Release-Please workflow.

However, I would like to generate release notes and a GitHub release specifically from the production branch. This approach aligns with best practices for cutting a release from the production branch.

The challenge arises when using Release-Please to cut a release from the production branch. In this case, the Git tags are not created in the development branch. If I were to utilize a different GitHub Action workflow to create the tags, Release-Please would not be aware of the Git tags generated by the other workflow.

I am seeking guidance on how to configure the Release-Please workflow to accommodate my use case effectively. Is there a way to make the Release-Please workflow work seamlessly in this scenario?

Additionally, I would appreciate advice on how to handle hotfixes within this context. How can we incorporate hotfixes into the workflow to ensure they are appropriately managed and accounted for?

Any assistance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

- GitHub Repository: [Any node.js Repo]
- Current Workflow: Release-Please
- Branches:

  - Development
  - Staging
  - Production